# What do you need to do after activating the generator in Blast Pit?

Tags: half-life

I'm playing the Blast Pit chapter of Half Life 1, and I can't continue or go back to the previous area.

I have already started the generator by activating the two switches on the top.

[image]

If I try to go back, this electrified water is going to kill me instantly (even with 100 health).

[image]

What do I need to do to continue the level?

Answer (score 2):

You have to **crawl over the pipes that run across the wall to the right side of it** by placing one of the blue boxes (that can be found underneath the cranes (and barnacles)) next to the larger box at the end of the hallway, **or drag those blue boxes over the electrified puddle** to get across.

[image: The proposed solution]

Comment: Unless you have the same problem I seem to have, where it's impossible to drag the boxes across the threshold of the door leading to the hallway.. (seems unrelated to using 'noclip', 'god', or even just 'sv_cheats').

Comment: Regarding my comment: disabling cheats, loading into another part of the map and then returning seems to have taken care of that problem.

Comment: @Lemon, did this work for you?